# Infinite Series of Rational Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Does anyone have a counterexample to the following conjecture?

Conjecture:

Suppose that the terms $a_{n}$ is a sequence of *rational numbers* and further that for *all* real numbers $r$, there are *infinitely many* $a_{n}$ with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \neq r$. This means, in particular that the sequence is NOT geometric. Then, the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$

either *diverges* or *converges to an irrational number.*

If this statement conjecture were true, it would imply that $\zeta(2n+1)$ is *irrational* for *all* $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, which (I believe) is still an *open problem.*

I know there are some results that say that if $a_{n}$ is a sequence of *integers* that grows *fast enough*, then $\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ is an *irrational number*, cf. results from Erdos and Strauss [in the following paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F61CA06EF543DADB8F3970EF30D9B5CC/S0017089500006868a.pdf/irrationality_of_certain_infinite_series.pdf)

Comment: We could let $a_1=1$ and all others be $0$ to get $1$

Comment: @KamalSaleh given the restriction is phrased in terms of quotients of the $a_n$, it should be safe to assume they are all nonzero. Also if it implies $\zeta(5)$ is rational then it's very unlikely anyone has a proof.

Comment: The series converges to an irrational number, like $\frac1{1×2}+\frac1{2×3}+...+\frac1{n(n+1)}+...$? $\rightarrow \leftarrow$

Comment: Yes, I meant to assume that each $a_{n}$ is nonzero.

Comment: Also, from what I understand, little is known about the zeta function values at odd numbers: $\zeta(2n+1)$. Has only $\zeta(3)$ been proven irrational?

Answer (score 2):

A derivative of an geometric power series answer your question.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n= \frac{1}{1-x} \Rightarrow
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
in particular
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}= \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2}=4$$
is a sequence of rational numbers converging to an rational number. Also taking $a_n=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$, we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$$
which is different from any real number infinitely many times.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would there still be a counterexample if I include the additional assumption that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = 1$? This assumption would still hold for all $\zeta(n)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, but would NOT hold for any derivative of a power series, i.e. $\frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^{n} = \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}x^{n-m}$

Comment: The series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$ telescopes and is equal to $1$. Also consider accept the answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!